# How to change tooltip background color vue-chartjs?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I've added `tooltips.backgroundColor` in `chartOptions` but still doesn't work, so anyone can help me?

Here is my code

```
<template>
  <Doughnut
    :chart-options="chartOptions"
    :chart-data="chartData"
    :chart-id="'doughnut-chart'"
    :styles="styles"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
  />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, type PropType } from "vue";
import TypographyComponent from "@/core/ui/components/typography/Typography.component.vue";
import { Doughnut } from "vue-chartjs";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ArcElement,
  CategoryScale,
  type Plugin,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale);

export default defineComponent({
  name: "ProgressChartComponent",
  components: { Doughnut, TypographyComponent },
  props: {
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400,
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400,
    },
    styles: {
      type: Object as PropType<Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>>,
      default: () => {},
    },
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const chartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      cutout: "64%",
      tooltips: {
        enabled: false,
        backgroundColor: "#227799",
      },
    };
    return {
      chartOptions,
    };
  },
});

</script>

...
```

Comment: The code, you posted here, is reported "enabled: false" therefore tooltip will never be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that you're using Chart.js v3, be aware that the tooltips are defined in the namespace `options.plugins.tooltip` but not `options.tooltips` as in your code. Therefore `chartOptions` needs to be changed as follows:

```
const chartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  cutout: "64%",
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: "#227799"
    }
  }
};
```

For further information, please consult [Tooltip Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration) from the Chart.js documentation.