ChartJS Tooltips aren't correctly displaying. What am I doing wrong?
I am trying to add extra information to my tooltips (when a user hovers over data point in a line chart) and the only information showed is the Player Count. It should include Player Count, Game Time, Game Date. Game Date isn't displayed in the chart, whilst Game Time is the x axis.
My script.js is below.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('table-form');
    var select = document.getElementById('tables');
    var chartContainer = document.getElementById('line-chart');
    var ctx = chartContainer.getContext('2d');
    var chart;
    var toggleDots = document.getElementById('toggle-dots');

    // Fetch tables from the database
    fetch('fetch_tables.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        data.forEach(function(table) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.text = table;
            select.add(option);
        });
    });

    // Form submission event listener
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectedTable = select.value;
        console.log('Selected table:', selectedTable); // Log selected table for debugging
        fetchData(selectedTable);
    });

    // Function to fetch data from the selected table
    function fetchData(table) {
        fetch('fetch_data.php?table=' + table)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            var labels = [];
            var counts = [];
            var gameDates = [];
            var gameTimes = [];

            data.forEach(function(entry) {
                labels.push(entry.GameTime);
                counts.push(Number(entry.PlayerCount)); // Convert PlayerCount to number before pushing
                gameDates.push(entry.GameDate); // Store GameDate
                gameTimes.push(entry.GameTime); // Store GameTime
            });

            console.log('Counts array:', counts); // Log counts array for debugging

            // Calculate statistics
            var maxPlayerCount = Math.max(...counts);
            var minPlayerCount = Math.min(...counts);
            var sumPlayerCount = counts.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
            var avgPlayerCount = sumPlayerCount / counts.length;

            console.log('Sum of player counts:', sumPlayerCount); // Log sum of player counts
            console.log('Average player count before rounding:', avgPlayerCount); // Log average player count before rounding

            // Ensure the average is rounded to two decimal places
            avgPlayerCount = parseFloat(avgPlayerCount.toFixed(2));

            console.log('Average player count after rounding:', avgPlayerCount); // Log average player count after rounding

            // Update statistics placeholders
            document.getElementById('highest-player-count').textContent = 'Highest Player Count: ' + maxPlayerCount;
            document.getElementById('lowest-player-count').textContent = 'Lowest Player Count: ' + minPlayerCount;
            document.getElementById('average-player-count').textContent = 'Average Player Count: ' + avgPlayerCount;

            // Draw chart
            drawChart(labels, counts, gameDates, gameTimes);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error)); // Log any errors
    }

    // Function to draw the chart
    function drawChart(labels, counts, gameDates, gameTimes) {
        if (chart) {
            chart.destroy();
        }

        chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Player Count',
                    data: counts,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    pointRadius: toggleDots.checked ? 3 : 0,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'day'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            autoSkip: true,
                            maxTicksLimit: 10
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Game Time'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Player Count'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            // Tooltip title will be the Game Date
                            var index = tooltipItem[0].index;
                            var gameDate = gameDates[index];
                            console.log('Tooltip title (Game Date):', gameDate); // Log gameDate
                            return 'Game Date: ' + gameDate;
                        },
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                            if (label) {
                                label += ': ';
                            }
                            label += tooltipItem.yLabel;
                            console.log('Tooltip label:', label); // Log tooltip label
                            return label;
                        },
                        afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            var index = tooltipItem.index;
                            var gameTime = gameTimes[index];
                            console.log('Tooltip afterLabel (Game Time):', gameTime); // Log gameTime
                            return 'Game Time: ' + gameTime;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        });
    }

    // Toggle event listener for data points
    toggleDots.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (chart) {
            chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
                dataset.pointRadius = this.checked ? 3 : 0;
            });
            chart.update();
        }
    });
});


I've tried debugging to the console to see if there are any errors that are fetched. No errors were posted in the inspect element console. And a matter of fact, none of the console.log messages were posted in the console. I've confirmed that the script.js is being correctly read and is in the current directory, I've changed the colour of the line graph and it changes so script.js is in the correct location. I've had a look at the documentation and think I am doing everything right.
I would just need peer checking to see and help point me out what I am doing wrong.

What version of Chart.js are you using?

@uminder - currently using 4.4.3. (Checked the source of the script https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js)

In that case, this answer may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73529158/2358409
